# Shell: Use variable within another variable-name (concatenation)

Tags: shell, concatenation

I have a few global variables named

```
ENV_URL_TEST1

ENV_URL_TEST2

ENV_URL_INT1
```

and so on.

My Question: -> I want to echo the value of these variables using another variable ($ENV):

```
echo ${ENV_URL_$ENV}
```

I have the String "TEST1" or "TEST2" or "INT1" and so on in that $ENV variable.

The above try results in a bad substitution error.
Is there a solution for my problem or is that not possible?

p.s. wanna use this within jenkins post build step, meaning **execute shell** step.

Comment: what is in your $ENV variable?

Comment: "I have the String "TEST1" or "TEST2" or "INT1" and so on in that $ENV variable."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `eval` :

```
$ ENV=TEST1
$ ENV_URL_TEST1='test_string'
$ eval echo \${ENV_URL_$ENV}
test_string
$ eval NEW_VAR=\${ENV_URL_$ENV}
$ echo $NEW_VAR
test_string
```

Comment: thank you, but does not work, my code: 
    echo "ENV: $ENV"
    eval echo \${ENV_URL_$ENV}  output console: + echo 'ENV: INT1'
ENV: INT1
+ eval echo '${ENV_URL_INT1}'
++ echo

Comment: Are you sure that ``ENV_URL_INT1`` has value ?

Comment: OMG you are sooo right, my fault, did change the names for stackoverflow ... now it works :) is there a chance to store the value to a new variable instead of echo-ing it?